# Dictionaries: how to compare values and merge if values are the same?

Tags: python

If I have two dictionaries:

```
 [{u'id': 217110,
  u'label': u'Business A',
  u'score': 0},
 {u'id': 217111,
  u'label': u'Business B',
  u'score': 0},
 {u'id': 217112,
  u'label': u'Business Yada Yada',
  u'score': 0'}]
```

and

```
[{u'City': u'Damariscotta',
  u'EntityType': u'Maine Public',
  u'EntityTypeCode': u'1',
  u'Status1': u'Open',
  u'ID': u'0188',
  u'Name1': u'A Company 000',
  u'UpdateTimeUnix': 1363756455},
{u'City': u'Santa Barbra',
  u'EntityType': u'California Public',
  u'EntityTypeCode': u'1',
  u'Status1': u'Delayed',
  u'ID': u'1001',
  u'Name1': u'Business A',
  u'UpdateTimeUnix': 1363758764},
{u'City': u'Boise',
  u'EntityType': u'Idaho Public',
  u'EntityTypeCode': u'1',
  u'Status1': u'Closed',
  u'ID': u'1012',
  u'Name1': u'Business Yada Yada',
  u'UpdateTimeUnix': 1363759375},
{u'City': u'Elkhart',
  u'EntityType': u'Indiana Public',
  u'EntityTypeCode': u'1',
  u'Status1': u'Open',
  u'ID': u'1016',
  u'Name1': u'Business B',
  u'UpdateTimeUnix': 1363826341}]
```

In short, what is an efficient way to get this?:

```
 [{u'id': 217110,
  u'label': u'Business A',
  u'score': 0,
  u'Status1': u'Delayed'},
 {u'id': 217111,
  u'label': u'Business B',
  u'score': 0,
  u'Status1': u'Open'},
 {u'id': 217112,
  u'label': u'Business Yada Yada',
  u'score': 0',
  u'Status1': u'Open'}]
```

Comment: Would you mind taking the time to explain what the criteria is? While it's nice to have a puzzle to solve - it shouldn't be working out what you're doing ;) Also - you're no doubt going to be asked what code you have so far...

Comment: He says "In short," before he actually tells us what he needs. What does the third list represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually not very interesting puzzle supposing that this two lists are joined by `u'label'` and `u'Name1'` respectively.

Now answering your question I'd say that efficient way would be to create index of elements in second list by `u'Name1'`

```
name_index = {item[u'Name1']: i for i, item in enumerate(list2)}
```

Then you could easily update items in first list with

```
for item in list1:
    item[u'Status1'] = list2[name_index[item[u'label']]][u'Status1']
```

NB: criteria of efficiency here is speed of getting status from second list

Answer (score 1):

Use operator.itemgetter:

```
from operator import itemgetter
key1 = itemgetter("Name1")
key2 = itemgetter("label")
key3 = itemgetter("Status1")
for record in b: # this is the longer list of dicts
    k = key1(record)
    for record2 in a: #this is the shorter one
        if key2(record2) == k:
            record2['Status1'] = key3(record)

print a
```

Outputs:

```
[{u'score': 0, 'Status1': u'Delayed', u'id': 217110, u'label': u'Business A'}, {u'score': 0, 'Status1': u'Open', u'id': 217111, u'label': u'Business B'}, {u'score': 0, 'Status1': u'Closed', u'id': 217112, u'label': u'Business Yada Yada'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this sounds like homework problem. We all encourage askers to post what they have written so that we can comment on it. Yet you have not shown us what you have done yet.

Second, the way the data is stored is not recommended. If the keys are from a small fixed set, you're better off using namedtuple in dictionary with unique key for each object. Especially for the second list, in which you have to iterate to find a name. In that case the name value will be the key. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Third, please be clear in your question. We take the time to help you, so please take your time to help us too.

Fourth, to do what you want:

```
for user in list1:
    for record in list2:
        if not record['Name1'] == user['label']:
            continue
        user['Status1'] = record['Status1']
```

This is, I believe, the simplest and most efficient way to complete the task. All operations are done in place without generating new object. Fancier search method is impossible in this case, since your object doesn't have key (it's a dictionary...). Linear search is the best we can do.